# C# DataTable Binary Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, binary, deserialization

Quick noob question which is really bothering me, I am serializing a DataTable array however when deserializing it back an exception is thrown for 'The input stream is not a valid binary format'

Serialization

```
    public static bool saveToFile(DataTable[] NW, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                formatter.Serialize(stream,NW);
                stream.Close();
                File.WriteAllBytes(path,stream.ToArray());
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Deserialization

```
public static DataTable[] loadFromFile(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (DataTable[])formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I've also tried it without the MemoryStream and used instead the File Stream returned by File.Open(string path, FileMode.Create/Open)

Also, just before writing it to the file this is the look of the byte array:

[image: M]

When reading it

:[image: e]

It looks like as it didn't really wrote everything to the file?

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to save it in binary format?
if not, DataSet has functionality to write all DataTables within it; into an xml file, and similarly you can read from the saved xml file.

Comment: It isn't mandatory to be binary, was trying to do it with binary so I can set RemotingFormat on each table to binary so it saves some space as data imported is quite big

Comment: I've just thrown your methods into a unit test with generated data.
Your code seems to be working fine. 
Do you have a sample data to go with your issue?
Have you checked for file size discrepancy on the physical file saved?

Comment: Thing is that the datatable is generated from several csv files, which browsing the table inside the debugger everything is there, issue is really when reading it.

Comment: Have you opening the saved file in a text editor? 
from running your code in a unit test, I'm seeing that it is writing out the xml for the datatable anyway and the file size is actually larger than a plain DataSet.WriteXml. Either ways, 
I'd first cross check the number of bytes read in by your loadFromFile method versus the actual number of bytes the file system says the file is. if the file size is the same, then there's nothing wrong with the read, it's reading all bytes from the file. first isolate where the problem is occurring.

Comment: here's a fiddle link to see your save and load methods in action
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gok577

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static class DataTableSerializer
{
    public static byte[] FastSerialize(this DataTable tbl, out string tableSchema)
    {
        var tableItems = new object[tbl.Rows.Count][];
        for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tbl.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
            tableItems[rowIndex] = tbl.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray;

        var serializationFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            serializationFormatter.Serialize(buffer, tableItems);

            var tableSchemaBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            tbl.WriteXmlSchema(new StringWriter(tableSchemaBuilder));
            tableSchema = tableSchemaBuilder.ToString();

            return buffer.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static DataTable FastDeserialize(byte[] serializedData, string tableSchema)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.ReadXmlSchema(new StringReader(tableSchema));

        var serializationFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        object[][] itemArrayForRows;

        using (var buffer = new MemoryStream(serializedData))
        {
            itemArrayForRows = (object[][]) serializationFormatter.Deserialize(buffer);
        }

        table.MinimumCapacity = itemArrayForRows.Length;
        table.BeginLoadData();

        for (var index = 0; index < itemArrayForRows.Length; index++)
        {
            var t = itemArrayForRows[index];
            table.Rows.Add(t);
        }

        table.EndLoadData();

        return table;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Lu Henry comment, It is actually working by moving the tables to a dataset and then write it.

```
    public static bool saveToFile(DataTable[] NW, string path)
    {

        try
        {
            var NWDS = new DataSet();
            foreach (DataTable dt in NW) {
                NWDS.Tables.Add(dt.Copy());
            }
            NWDS.WriteXml(File.Create(path));
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }


    public static DataTable[] loadFromFile(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var NWDS = new DataSet();
            NWDS.ReadXml(File.Open(path,FileMode.Open));
            var NW = new DataTable[15];
            NWDS.Tables.CopyTo(NW,0);
            return NW;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }
```